# Error setting property values (Spring 3+mybatis 3)

Tags: spring, mybatis

My Application uses Spring 3 + MyBatis 3. I'm trying to setup multiple database connection (MySQL and Oracle), and I got this message.

```
Error creating bean with name 'MySQLService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appContext-database.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'MySQLDao' of bean class [com.ekalife.MyGadget.service.MainService]: Bean property 'MySQLDao' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

My setup appContext-database.xml

```
<!-- ========== Setting Database and Connection Pooling ========== -->

<bean id="dataSourceMySQL" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" 
    p:driverClass="${jdbc.driver}" 
    p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}" 
    p:user="${jdbc.user}" 
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" 
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="3600" 
    p:preferredTestQuery="SELECT * FROM HD_USERS" 
    p:acquireRetryAttempts="50" 
    p:autoCommitOnClose="false" /> 

<bean id="dataSourceORA" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverORA}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.urlORA}"
    p:user="${jdbc.userORA}"
    p:password="${jdbc.passwordORA}"
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="3600"
    p:preferredTestQuery="SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL"
    p:acquireRetryAttempts="50"
    p:autoCommitOnClose="false"/>

<!-- transaction manager -->
<bean id="MySQLService" class=" com.ekalife.MyGadget.service.MainService">
    <property name="MySQLDao" ref="MySQLDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ORAService" class=" com.ekalife.MyGadget.service.OraService">
    <property name="ORADao" ref="ORADao"/>
</bean>

<!-- MySQL transactional advice -->
<tx:advice id="mySqlTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManagerMySQL">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="select" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="view" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="mySQLManagerMethods" expression="execution(* com.ekalife.MyGadget.service.MainService.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="mySqlTxAdvice" pointcut-ref="mySQLManagerMethods" />
</aop:config>
<bean id="transactionManagerMySQL" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMySQL" />
</bean>

<!-- Oracle transactional advice -->
<tx:advice id="oraTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManagerORA">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="select" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="view" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="oraManagerMethods" expression="execution(* com.ekalife.MyGadget.service.OraService.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="oraTxAdvice" pointcut-ref="oraManagerMethods" />
</aop:config>
<bean id="transactionManagerORA" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceORA"/>
</bean>

<bean id="MySQLDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSourceMySQL"
    p:mapperLocations="classpath*:com/ekalife/MyGadget/dao/MySQL/**/*.xml"
    p:typeAliasesPackage="com.ekalife.MyGadget.model" />
<bean id="MySQLDaoSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="MySQLDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ORADao" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSourceORA" 
    p:mapperLocations="classpath*:com/ekalife/MyGadget/dao/Ora/**/*.xml"
    p:typeAliasesPackage="com.ekalife.MyGadget.model" />
<bean id="ORADaoSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="ORADao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="MySQLMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean" 
    p:sqlSessionTemplate-ref="MySQLDaoSessionTemplate"
    p:mapperInterface="com.ekalife.MyGadget.dao.MainMapper"
    p:sqlSessionFactory-ref="MySQLDao"/>
<bean id="ORAMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean" 
    p:sqlSessionTemplate-ref="ORADaoSessionTemplate"
    p:mapperInterface="com.ekalife.MyGadget.dao.OraMapper"
    p:sqlSessionFactory-ref="ORADao"/>
```

MySQL Service

```
package com.ekalife.MyGadget.service;

@Transactional
public class MainService {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainService.class);

    @Autowired
    private MainMapper mainMapper;
```

Oracle Service

```
@Transactional
public class OraService {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainService.class);

    @Autowired
    private OraMapper oraMapper;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: but i couldnt see a property with mysqldao in service class and its setter method also :(, is it something related to @transaction ? or it should be there

Comment: is it must be 
@Transactional("MySQLDao")
public class MainService ?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `MySQLDao` in your `MainService` and its setter and getter because Spring is looking for it.

Another error is that variable name should start with lowcase:

```
<bean id="MySQLService" class=" com.ekalife.MyGadget.service.MainService">
    <property name="mySQLDao" ref="MySQLDao"/>
</bean>
```

Also, I see some incoherence. Your `MainService` has a property `mainMapper` that it is autowired but also, in the applications context xml you want to inyect `mySQLDao`

It is better to choose the same strategy for all inyection. For example, I propose you inyect all in the xml configuration:

```
<bean id="MySQLService" class=" com.ekalife.MyGadget.service.MainService">
    <property name="mySQLDao" ref="MySQLDao"/>
    <property name="mainMapper" ref="MySQLMapper"/>
</bean>
```

**UPTATED**: Answering your question "how to declare MySQLDao in MainService"

```
package com.ekalife.MyGadget.service;

// imports...

@Transactional
public class MainService {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainService.class);

    private MainMapper mainMapper;

    private SqlSessionFactoryBean mySQLDao;

    // your methods

    // setter and getter methods for mySQLDao and mainMapper

}
```

Comment: how to declare MySQLDao in MainService? is there a simple way to setup multiple connection (mysql and oracle) in Spring?

Comment: See my updated to see how to declare MySQLDao. There is no a simple way to declare two data sources in Spring, at least, as you are expecting.

Comment: I got another message "Error creating bean with name 'MySQLService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appContext-database.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory' to required type 'org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean' for property 'mySQLDao': no matching editors or conversion strategy found "

Comment: Take a look to the packages. Classes names are the same, but the packages are not. You need need to fix that.

Comment: in my case, mapper packages was com.ekalife.MyGadget.dao.MainMapper, service package was com.ekalife.MyGadget.service.MainService; is mapper must be in com.ekalife.MyGadget.service or not? because I make another appContext-database.xml (without aop or tx) only for oracle or only mysql and it was running well.

Comment: What I meant was that 'org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory' and 'org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean' are different classes and that is why you get and error.

Comment: I didn't use 'org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory' only 'org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean'.

Comment: Review 'mySQLDao' type in your MainServide, it should be 'SqlSessionFactoryBean'

Comment: yes, it was 
public class MainService {
 private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainService.class); 
 private MainMapper mainMapper; 
 private SqlSessionFactoryBean mySQLDao;

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you are getting the error is because you don't have getter and setter for you Mainservice and OraService class. The Spring Error it even tells you that in away "is not writable or has an invalid setter method".